# JSON: Unrecognized field exception in spite of having all fields in POJO and JSON file

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have seen multiple answers to this problem in stackoverflow and outside. But I am not able to understand the real issue here.

I have a pojo class which is given below.

```
public class User{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String location;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String gethouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }
    public void sethouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

I have a JSON file as follows:

```
   [{
          "id":1,
          "name": "roy",
          "houseNumber":"No/242",
           "location" :"Germany"
    },
    {
          "id":2,
          "name": "philip",
          "houseNumber":"No/252",
           "location" :"Germany"
    }]
```

Every json entry of the file has the field location with a value. But why am I getting the exception Unrecognized field "location" inspite of having the field in both my POJO and the JSON file? I would like to know the reason of this. Many solutions suggest using annotations for JSON like `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. It did not work for me.

Comment: post complete POJO including getter and setter

Comment: Posted JSON represent the list of Users. Do you deserialize it as a list or as User object? If you are trying to convert that JSON to the User object then you would get UnrecognizedProperty exception.

Comment: I am deserializing it as a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using camel case correctly on your getters and setters, I know that does sometimes cause Jackson to produce unexpected results.

```
public String getName() {
        return name;
  }
 public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
 }
 public String getHouseNumber() {
    return houseNumber;
 }
public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
    this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it works fine for me
The @JsonIgnoreProperties is not required. you can do the following

```
  String jsonString = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\": \"roy\",\"houseNumber\":\"No/242\",\"location\" :\"Germany\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\": \"philip\",\"houseNumber\":\"No/252\",\"location\" :\"Germany\"}]";
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      List<User> a = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<ArrayList<User>>() {});
```